# How to get the 'id' property of a Socket object in SocketIO?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

Basically what I'm trying to do is to get the 'id' property of the Socket object to save every current client socket id into the DB, but struggling to get the 'id' property. I see it in the console.log, but I can't get the value itself.

```
componentDidMount() {
this.addUpdateCurrentRequestsView();
const firstSocket = primarySocket('http://localhost:3001');
console.log(firstSocket.id)// this is undefined
console.log(firstSocket) //id property is visible in console
this.registerUpdateCurrentSocket(firstSocket.id);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle things in a connection.

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
 //socket is here
})
```

Did you check the documents?

Comment: Yes, this would work as well as setting an interval, less cumbersome though in deed.

Comment: this is the way you're supposed to do it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe I solved this issue by trial and error. If you guys ever run into an issue where a property is not accessible even though it shows up in console.log, I believe it's an asynchronous issue where it's not there yet so to speak. So I tried this code.

```
let firstSocketIDAssignmentChecker = setInterval(()=>{
    if (firstSocket.id!==undefined){
        this.registerUpdateCurrentSocket(firstSocket.id);
        clearInterval(firstSocketIDAssignmentChecker);
    }
},100);
```

And this works.